# How to assign column-level restriction on BigQuery table in asia-east1 location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I want to restrict access to certain PII columns of my BigQuery tables. My tables are present in location: asia-east1. The BigQuery 'Policy Tag' feature can create policy tags for enforcing column restrictions only in 'US' and 'EU' regions. When I try to assign these policy tags to my asia-east1 tables, it fails with error:

BigQuery error in update operation: Policy tag reference projectsproject-id/locations/us/taxonomies/taxonomy-id/policyTags/policytag-id
should contain a location that is in the same region as the dataset.

Any idea on how I can implement this column level restriction for my asia-east1 BigQuery tables?

Comment: According to the documentation, if you are using a Data Catalog in Asia, you can use the data endpoint in Taiwan, [link](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/concepts/regions?hl=en). Also, can you check if you followed all the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security). Did any of these instructions work for you?

Comment: Yes Alexandre, I followed all the steps. This feature seems to be in Beta mode, that's the reason it has not been rolled out to all the regions yet. Unfortunately I wont be able to use 'Policy Tags' feature for enforcing column-level security unless and until they make it available for asia-east1 :(

Comment: yes ! The Policy Tags are not available to all regions yet. As I mentioned above you can find a workaround using a different location in the same region. Also, would you mind if I summarise our discussion as an answer in order to further contribute with the community?

Comment: Sure Alexandre, no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarising our discussion from the comment section.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security-intro?hl=en), BigQuery provides fine grained  access to sensitive data based on type or data classification of the data. In order to achieve this, you can use Data Catalog  to create a the taxonomy and policy for your data.

Regarding the location of the Policy tags, asia-east1. Currently, this feature is on [Beta](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages). This is a launch stage where the product is available for broader testing and use and new features/updates might be still taking place. For this reason, Data Catalog locations are limited to the ones listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/concepts/regions?hl=en). As shown in the link, ***asia-east1*** end point has ***Taiwan*** as the region.

As an addition information, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security) is a How to guide to implement Policy Tags in BigQuery.